# Which version of Mathematica did DiracDelta become to the derivative of HeavisideTheta from that of UnitStep?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, compatibility

The mathematica's version of my coworkers is 5.0, they use `UnitStep` to derive formula, However, I also want to use the **parallel** features so used the latest version 11.3. then I found `UnitStep` in the two versions is different, the `UnitStep`'s derivative in 5.0 is `DiracDelta`, but not in 11.3. In version 11.3, `DiracDelta` becomes `HeavisideTheta`'s derivative. I want to know:

1. Which is the first version where the difference appeared?
2. If `HeavisideTheta[0]=1`, is `HeavisideTheta` in v11.3 equal to `UnitStep`
   in v5.0?
3. Can I replace `UnitStep` to `HeavisdeTheta`?

Thanks!

In version 5.0

[image]

In version 11.3

[image]

Comment: Can I summarize the question as, you need a `UnitStep` that differentiates to `DiracDelta`? Is there any other feature required?

Comment: @xzczd , Thanks for your attention, we always got different results using `UnitStep` in MMA 5.X and MMA 11.3 to derive symbolic formulas, we also have used `HeavisideTheata` in 11.3 to derive, but the results are different from correct results, so our work group use 5.0 when deriving symbolic formulas ,then use 11.3 when calculating and plotting because the graphics are better in 11.3 than in 5.0.

Comment: @xzczd ,I want to know if I can copy the function `UnitStep` in 5.0 as a package to 11.3 like in Matlab copying a function definition file to a work folder, or can I use a command in 11.3 to call `UnitStep` locating in 5.0 directory? Thank you.

Comment: I think it's hard (if not impossible) because `UnitStep` is a built-in function. Perhaps some clever use of mathlink (Now it's called WSTP link) will help? I've no idea. "We also have used `HeavisideTheta` in 11.3 to derive, but the results are different from correct results" This sounds strange, can you show a specific example?

Comment: @xzczd, my meaning is: 5.0 can got correct results different from 11.3's fault  when using `UnitStep`, and 11.3  failed to get right result too when using `HeavisideTheata` to replace of `UnitStep`. The codes can not be pasted here because it's too long. Thank you.

Comment: Well, I still think it's better to figure out why 11.3 doesn't deduce the correct result. Creating a minimal example should not be too hard. Anyway, it's your choice.

Answer (score 3):

This script is from a Mathematica version 6.0 session using 'math.exe'

```
Mathematica 6.0 for Microsoft Windows (32-bit)
Copyright 1988-2008 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:= D[#@x, x] & /@ {UnitStep, HeavisideTheta}

Out[1]= {Piecewise[{{Indeterminate, x == 0}}], DiracDelta[x]}

In[2]:=
```

Comment: Thank you for providing these information, you verified my guess at the same time. MMA 6.0 substitutes `ArrayFlatten, ConstantArray, Take`...  for `BlockMatrix, ZeroMatrix, TakeMatrix`..., so I guess from where `UnitStep` and `HeavisideTheta` came to an change. would you proceed to answer question 2 and 3 mentioned above?

Comment: @likehust I would if I had access to version 5.0 but I don't.

Answer (score 1):

> If `HeavisideTheta[0] = 1`, is `HeavisideTheta` in v11.3 equal to `UnitStep` in v5.0?

For calculus purposes, sure.

[image: version 5.2 session]

> Can I replace `UnitStep` with `HeavisideTheta`?

`HeavisideTheta[]` is what you should be using in version 6 and later versions, because it's the one now supported extensively by the calculus functions. In earlier functions, you have to settle for `UnitStep[]`.

---

You can always use `$VersionNumber` along with conditionals (e.g. `If[]`, `Which[]`) to write code that does different things depending on the version the code is evaluated in.

```
If[$VersionNumber >= 6., HeavisideTheta'[x], UnitStep'[x]]
```

Comment: Yesterday, My coworker got different results in MM10 and MM5.0 while running same program codes. Now, I am transferring my own codes from MM10 to MM5.0  in hoping to find a good luck by changing `HeavisideTheta[]` to `UnitStep[]`, certainly, it's a hard work because involving  the replacement of other functions such as `ParallelMap, ArrayFlatten, ParallelNeeds, ConstantArray`, and so on.