# How to call an old build-in function in a new version of Mathematica?

Tags: functions, external-calls, compatibility

In order to use the `UnitStep` of Mathematica 5.2, I have to install two different versions 5.2 and 11.3 at the same time because `Unitstep` is different in the two versions (`UnitStep` has different derivatives in the two different verions of Mathematica, I listed the difference [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/195465/which-version-of-mathematica-did-diracdelta-become-to-the-derivative-of-heavisid)). Today I suddenly think of that: Can I call the old version `UnitStep` of MMA 5.2 in the new Mathematica 11.3? How to realize if it's true? Thank you.

Comment: @ Nasser, the MathKernel.exe will not run, but the math.exe can run in the CMD window correctly.

Comment: You can use version 5.2 Kernel from newer kernel via MathLink: "[Executing code in v.5.2 kernel from within v.7.01 session through MathLink](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4983301/590388)."

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, thank you, it's a good solution, but too complex and easily generates error. I continue to combine 5.2 and 11.3 because I can debug codes with ease.

Comment: I'm curious, what you mean by "I continue to combine 5.2 and 11.3"? How do you do that?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, To use 5.2 when deriving symbolic formulas because it always gives anticipating results using `UnitStep`, then use 11.3 when calculating and plotting because the graphics are better in 11.3 than in 5.2