# use mathematica low version in mathematica high version

Tags: performance-tuning, compatibility

it's known to all that ,sometimes higher version is far more slow than low version

this is a example.

```
Clear["Global`*"]; Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

on my computer

[image]

[image]

So is there a way to use low version in high version?

The reason why I don't use low version directly is that high version has more functions,which is more convenient.

**thx to the link in the comment.I find this.**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983301/executing-code-in-v-5-2-kernel-from-within-v-7-01-session-through-mathlink

Comment: No, not possible

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/209225/1871

Comment: @b3m2a1 actually it did work.

Comment: @wuyudi you’re not using the functions in the old version in the new one, but rather calling into the old one in the new one. That’s gonna introduce calling overhead that will obliterate the performance gain that motivated your question in the first place.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's possible with `` Graphics`Legacy`Plot ``:

[image]

*Update in respond to comment about 3D:*

First, [@Jens's webpage](https://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/MathematicaVersions.html) has some discussion of graphics changes in V5, 6, 7, and 8. It has not been updated since 2012, but for its historical interest, it seems relevant to this Q&A. In particular, the package `` "Graphics`Graphics3D`" `` no longer exists AFAICT. You can still override the current plotters with `` << Version5`Graphics` ``. (I think you have to quit the kernel to restore them. There's also a `` "Version6`Graphics`" `` package to restore V6 graphics. These mainly exist, it seems, to provide some backwards compatibility with old notebooks.)

The legacy 3D plotters produce `SurfaceGraphics[..]` instead of `Graphics3D[..]`.  There's not much point, other than historical interest, but here's a way to convert them to `Graphics3D` objects, with different styling.  The conversion pretty much takes away any speed gain, so it's pointless as far as that goes.

```
SurfaceGraphicsToGraphics3D = # /. 
    SurfaceGraphics[data_, opts_] :>
     (*Visualization`Core`*)ListPlot3D[data, 
      DataRange -> OptionValue[SurfaceGraphics, opts, MeshRange], 
      FilterRules[opts, Options@ListPlot3D]] &;

Graphics`Legacy`Plot3D[
  Sin[x y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}] // AbsoluteTiming
Graphics`Legacy`Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}] // 
  SurfaceGraphicsToGraphics3D // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Using `` Visualization`Core`ListPlot3D `` saves about half the time over `ListPlot3D`. `ListPlot3D`, like other plotters, does some preprocessing before calling its internal version `` Visualization`Core`ListPlot3D ``. You probably lose some functionality and safeguards bypassing the top level `ListPlot3D`, but maybe it's worth it to you. Once upon a time, I'd do things in graphics directly and bypass plotters, but computers are pretty fast now. A plot that is too slow is usually due to the function, not to the plotter.  Sometimes in `Manipulate` a tenth of a second can make a difference in the user experience, so to manipulate a fixed example, it might make sense to bypass `Plot3D`, which takes about a tenth of a second on the example below. Here's a pretty dumb 3D plotter, similar to the legacy one, with only one option implemented:

```
ClearAll[plot3D];
SetAttributes[plot3D, HoldAll];
plot3D[f_, {x_, x1_, x2_}, {y_, y1_, y2_}, 
   opts : OptionsPattern[Plot3D]] :=
  With[{pp = OptionValue[PlotPoints] /. Automatic -> 25},
   With[{data = Flatten[
       Table[{x, y, f}, {x, Subdivide[N@x1, N@x2, pp - 1]}, {y, 
         Subdivide[N@y1, N@y2, pp - 1]}],
       1]},
    Graphics3D[
     GraphicsComplex[
      data,
      (Flatten /@ Flatten[
           Partition[Partition[Range@Length@data, pp], {2, 2}, {1, 1}],
           1])[[All, {1, 2, 4, 3}]] // Polygon
      ], FilterRules[{opts}~Join~Options@Plot3D, Options@Graphics3D]]
    ]];

plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it will crashed inside `Table` or `Manipulate`.For example: ``Table[Graphics`Legacy`Plot[ Sin[x + a], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], {a, 1, 5}]``

Comment: it seems that this function has a little problem. But it is really fast. `Graphics\`Legacy\`Plot[Tan[x], {x, 0, Pi}]`

Comment: ok,I find this. `Visualization\`Core\`Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}]` ,which can draw 3D

Comment: @matrix89 Try it thus: ``Table[With[{a = a}, Graphics`Legacy`Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 0, 5}]], {a, 2}]``

Comment: @wuyudi Do you mean the "little problem" is the extra vertical line in ``Graphics`Legacy`Plot[Tan[x], {x, 0, Pi}]`` compared to ``Plot[Tan[x], {x, 0, Pi}]``? One reason the new `Plot` is slower than the legacy `Plot` is that it does extra analysis to exclude discontinuities as well as other preprocessing (plot themes, `Quantity[]`, etc.); the new plotters also do better adaptive refinement, too. -- Note that ``Visualization`Core`Plot3D`` is pretty much the same as `Plot3D` minus the automatic option processing. To get closer to the legacy function add the option `MaxRecursion -> 0`.

Answer (score 1):

I find this link. And change a little.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4992265

here is the code.

```
Clear[linkEvaluate]
SetAttributes[linkEvaluate, HoldRest]
linkEvaluate[link_LinkObject, expr_] := 
  Catch[Module[{out = {}, postScript = {}, packet, outputs = {}}, 
    While[LinkReadyQ[link], 
     Print["From the buffer:\t", LinkRead[link]]];
    LinkWrite[link, Unevaluated[EnterExpressionPacket[expr]]];
    While[Not@MatchQ[packet = LinkRead[link], InputNamePacket[_]], 
     Switch[packet, DisplayPacket[_], 
      AppendTo[postScript, First@packet], DisplayEndPacket[_], 
      AppendTo[postScript, First@packet];
      CellPrint@
         Cell[GraphicsData["PostScript", #], "Output", 
          CellLabel -> "Kernel 5.2 PostScript ="] &@
       StringJoin[postScript]; postScript = {}, TextPacket[_], 
      If[StringMatchQ[First@packet, 
        WordCharacter .. ~~ "::" ~~ WordCharacter .. ~~ ": " ~~ __], 
       CellPrint@
        Cell[BoxData@
          RowBox[{StyleBox["Kernel 5.2 Message = ", 
             FontColor -> Blue], First@packet}], "Message"], 
       CellPrint@
        Cell[First@packet, "Output", 
         CellLabel -> "Kernel 5.2 Print"]], OutputNamePacket[_], 
      AppendTo[outputs, First@packet];, ReturnExpressionPacket[_], 
      AppendTo[outputs, First@packet];, _, AppendTo[out, packet]]];
    If[Length[out] > 0, Print[out]];
    Which[(l = Length[outputs]) == 0, Null, l == 2, Last@outputs, 
     True, multipleOutput[outputs]]]];
Clear[kernel8Evaluate]
SetAttributes[kernel8Evaluate, HoldAll]
kernel8Evaluate[expr_] := 
 If[TrueQ[MemberQ[Links[], $kern8]], linkEvaluate[$kern8, expr], 
  Clear[$kern8]; $kern8 = 
   LinkLaunch[
    "C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram \
Research\\Mathematica\\8.0\\MathKernel.exe -mathlink"];(*the address of your MathKernel*)
  LinkRead[$kern8];
  LinkWrite[$kern8, 
   Unevaluated[EnterExpressionPacket[$MessagePrePrint = InputForm;]]];
  LinkRead[$kern8]; kernel8Evaluate[expr]]
```

and here is the result.

[image]

Comment: How useful is this to deal with the performance problem you described? The overhead of calling another kernel process may be significant. Also, definitions will not be shared between the kernels, which limits the usefulness of this approach.

Comment: @SzabolcsSz well，it is really sort of useless.But this really happens: some question that new version is short to solve while old version is able to solve.